# How do I parse delimited rows of text with differing field counts in to objects, while allowing for extension?

Tags: java, string, parsing

An example is as follows:

```
SEG1|asdasd|20111212|asdsad
SEG2|asdasd|asdasd
SEG3|sdfsdf|sdfsdf|sdfsdf|sdfsfsdf
SEG4|sdfsfs|
```

Basically, each `SEG*` line needs to be parsed into a corresponding object, defining what each of those fields are. Some, such as the third field in `SEG1` will be parsed as a `Date`.

Each object will generally stay the same but there may be instances in which an additional field may be added, like so:

`SEG1|asdasd|20111212|asdsad|12334455`

At the moment, I'm thinking of using the following type of algorithm:

```
List<String> segments = Arrays.asList(string.split("\r"); // Will always be a CR.
List<String> fields;
String fieldName;
for (String segment : segments) {
    fields = Arrays.asList(segment.split("\\|");
    fieldName = fields.get(0);
    SEG1 seg1;
    if (fieldName.compareTo("SEG1") == 0) {
        seg1 = new Seg1();
        seg1.setField1(fields.get(1));
        seg1.setField2(fields.get(2));
        seg1.setField3(fields.get(3));
    } else if (fieldName.compareTo("SEG2") == 0) {
        ...
    } else if (fieldName.compareTo("SEG3") == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        // Erroneous/failure case.
    }
}
```

Some fields may be optional as well, depending on the object being populated. My concern is if I add a new field to a class, any checks that use the expect field count number will also need to be updated. How could I go about parsing the rows, while allowing for new or modified field types in the class objects to populate?

Comment: To further clarify my example, the same classes are used to create the string example, and then import into and populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define a common interface for all to be parsed classes I would suggest the following:

```
interface Segment {}

class SEG1 implements Segment
{
    void setField1(final String field){};
    void setField2(final String field){};
    void setField3(final String field){};
}

enum Parser {
    SEGMENT1("SEG1") {
        @Override
        protected Segment parse(final String[] fields)
        {
            final SEG1 segment = new SEG1();
            segment.setField1(fields[0]);
            segment.setField1(fields[1]);
            segment.setField1(fields[2]);
            return segment;
        }
    },        
    ...
    ;

    private final String name;

    private Parser(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected abstract Segment parse(String[] fields);

    public static Segment parse(final String segment)
    {
        final int firstSeparator = segment.indexOf('|');

        final String name = segment.substring(0, firstSeparator);
        final String[] fields = segment.substring(firstSeparator + 1).split("\\|");

        for (final Parser parser : values())
            if (parser.name.equals(name))
                return parser.parse(fields);

        return null;
    }
}
```

For each type of segment add an element to the enum and handle the different kinds of fields in the `parse(String[])`method.

Comment: You could also use a `Map<String,Parser>` instead of an `enum` if you want to be able to distribute the code over multiple files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up following a similar type of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use collections, e.g. ArrayList
2. You can use [var-args](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

If you want to make it extensible, you may want to process each segment in a loop, instead of handling each occurance.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

How would wrapping the `List` in an `ArrayList` benefit me in this instance? All I need to do is loop through the segments and then process each of the fields individually, essentially calling the mutator method of the object I'm populating. 

I will have to do some more reading on varargs.

Comment: If you have a segment with unknown number of fields, you can simply use 'split()' and store the resulting array in the ArrayList. Arrays won't be handy as number of fields are not known, that's why I suggested ArrayList. Also, which message format are you trying to parse? HL7? Just curious.

Comment: It is HL7 :) A subset of it. Some fields are used, others are ommitted. My thoughts on extensibility were around allowing other fields to be added down the track, should they be required. I have a known number of fields for each segment so I'm trying to think of how best to process/parse that, while allowing for those additions.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a header row to your file format with the names of the fields being stored in the file so it looks something more like this:

```
(1) field1|field2|field3|field4|field5
(2) SEG1|asdasd|20111212|asdsad|
(3) SEG2|asdasd||asdasd|
(4) SEG3|sdfsdf|sdfsdf|sdfsdf|sdfsfsdf
(5) SEG4|sdfsfs|||
```

This is common for CSV files. I've also added more delimiters so that each line has five 'values'. This way a `null` value can be specified by just entering two delimiters in a row (see the third row above for an example where a `null` value is not the last value).

Now your parsing code knows what fields need to be set and you can call the setters using reflection in a loop. Pseudo code:

```
get the field names from the first line in the file

for (every line in the file except the first one) {

    for (every value in the line) {

        if (the value is not empty) {

            use reflection to get the setter for the field and invoke it with the
            value
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to extend the file with additional fields without having to change the code. It also means you can have meaningful field names. The reflection may get a bit complicated with different types e.g. `int`, `String`, `boolean` etc. so I would have to say that if you can, follow @sethu's advice and use a ready-built proven library that does this for you.

Comment: Personally I only use reflection when nothing else can do the job. I like my type safety ;)

Comment: @CKuck Yeah it does sacrifice type safety for flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a necessity to use the same string with | as a delimiter? If the same classes are used to create the String, then its an ideal case for Xstream. Xstream will convert your java object into XML and back. Xstream will take care of the scenario where some fields are optional. You will not have write any code that parses your text. Here's a link:

http://x-stream.github.io/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a specific messaging format so it requires `|` separated fields with carriage return separated segments. Thanks for the advice though. Also, not sure why someone gave you a -1. I didn't think the suggestion was bad.